# Suricata gateway not decode http protocol

Tags: suricata

I have a test like this:

My env:

os:debian 8

```
A:172.20.0.1 (gateway  suricata v3.2 )

B:172.20.0.2  (App Server)

C:172.20.0.3  (Client)
```

My network:

```
client(C)  ----> gateway suricata A (ids)  -----> AppServer B
```

My suricata build info:

```
wget https://github.com/inliniac/suricata/archive/suricata-3.2.zip
unar suricata-3.2.zip
cd suricata-3.2
git clone https://github.com/OISF/libhtp.git
./configure --enable-nfqueue --enable-pfring --enable-hiredis --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var
make
make install
make install-conf
make install-rules
```

And load only a test rule:

```
alert http any any -> any any (msg:"http test"; content:"GET";) #no.1
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"tcp test"; content:"GET";) #no.2
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"tcp http test"; content:"GET";http_method;) #no.3
```

A:172.20.0.1 (gateway suricata) OS info:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -F
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

Client send a request as

```
 'http://172.20.0.2/test'
```

tail the fast.log.  Only the #no.2 rule is matched

I have try opened the nat with iptables like:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

And this time the #no.1 #no.2 #no.3 rules matched

But, The nat was opened that  the appserver didn`t get the right client ip

address.

And now , I want use the 7 layer protocol something parameters like 
http_uri,http_method and so on. The nat must be closed.

I want the right way ~ ~ ~   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foun a way that:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j TEE --gateway 172.20.8.147
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j TEE --gateway 172.20.8.147
```

and the NAT is too badly,

the topic close